# How to set delegate to another controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have one view controller (`AViewController`) and there I have table.
In that controller I have added another view controller view as a subview (`BViewController`):

```
BViewController *barCodeScanner = [[BViewController alloc]init];
[self.view addSubview:barCodeScanner.view];
```

`BViewController` has a delegate and one delegate method in it and it works.
But I want to refresh table on `AViewController`.
So I moved delegate to `AViewController` and try to change delegate code from:

```
rdr.readerDelegate = self;
```

to

```
rdr.readerDelegate = AViewController;
```

but it doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create an instance for AViewController and set it as a delegate to `rdr`:

```
rdr.readerDelegate = aViewControllerInstance;
```

Answer (score 3):

`AViewController` is a type (a class) , not an *instance* of the type. Delegate accepts the instance of class, not class name.

Answer (score 1):

hi may be this will clear you question.

```
AViewController *aView = [[AViewController alloc]init];

rdr.readerDelegate = aView ;
```

You need to set the object of `AViewController` as the delegate.